# Bitflag to int C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm consuming a web API and I need to pass in an int value that corresponds to a bit flag. How do I calculate the int values to pass in? For instance, if I want Option B, Option E, and Option F - what would the corresponding int value be?

Also please give a few more examples, like if I only want Option G. Or if I want D and E.

```
[Flags] public enum Includes
    {
        OptionA = 1 << 0,
        OptionB = 1 << 1,
        OptionC = 1 << 2,
        OptionD = 1 << 3,
        OptionE = 1 << 4,
        OptionF = 1 << 5,
        OptionG = 1 << 6,
        OptionH = 1 << 7
    }

int includes = ????
```

Comment: An enum *is* an int unless you specify a different type. You could cast an `Includes` value to an int directly, or even store it in an `int` variable and vice versa. If your controller action accepts an `Includes` enum the value will be cast automatically

Comment: `int includes = (int)(Includes.OptionB | Includes.OptionE | Includes.OptionF)`

Comment: In fact, when you have an `Enum` parameter you have to explicitly check the input because the compiler doesn't ensure the caller passed a valid enum value.

Comment: I'm seeing examples where the previous person passed in for instance '29' and it gives wildly different answers as if I were to pass in '2'. So I think there is a way to assign a unique value to all combinations?

Comment: @MobileMon that's a different question. 2 and 29 set different bits. A bitflag reflects those bits. As for setting an `all` value, that's 127 or 0x7F - all lower bits set to 1

Comment: I guess the title of my question is misstated but the body of my question remains. How do I calculate the unique int for different combination of options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I calculate the int values to pass in?

By using bitwise OR, in that same way that this works:

```
int seven = 1|2|4;
```

Because in binary 1 is 0001, 2 is 0010 and 4 is 0100 when OR'd together they become 0111 (7)

> Option B, Option E, and Option F

```
int bef = (int)(Includes.OptionB | Includes.OptionE | Includes.OptionF);
```

You can imagine the pattern you need to use for others. It doesn't matter what order you OR them in

For decoding a number we use a similar trick with &:

```
if(bef & Includes.OptionB == Includes.OptionB)
```

There is a helper method Enum.HasFlag you can use too

Comment: The problem is I'm passing this in to a Web API so its not c# to c#. If it were c# to c#, these solutions would work but I'm passing it in via JSON

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the problem. Your JSON is being prepared by javascript? Press F12 to open your browser console. Type into it `1|2|4` and press return, watch it print 7 - JS understands the same bitwise OR operator that C# does. The JSON is being prepared by C#? Any of the advice given will work.. I'm not even sure on which end of the pipe the C# in our question is (server or client?) but it's all just numbers

Comment: B E F is 1,4,5, so the int you want is `2^1 + 2^4 + 2^5`, or `2^1 | 2^4 | 2^5`, or `1<<1 | 1<<4 | 1<<5` or ...

Comment: ok that makes sense, I'm actually using dart but saying 'int i = 1 | 2 | 4' works in dart as well. Thanks. I really appreciate the answer!

Comment: Dart looks like it supports bitshift too, so I dare say that any combination of "2 to the power x" or "1 bitshifted by x" will give you an int and any combination of "arithemtic add" or "bitwise or" will combine them; some constant names to match the c# enum and you're good to go!